# why file picker intent is returning null path on android 4.4?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.4-kitkat

so I have the code below working fine until android 4.4. I was able to get the path from the uri by `intent.getData()` in `onActivityResult` then do something special about the uri to get the path of the photo that was selected.

```
private Intent createPhotoIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    Intent chooser = createPhotoChooserIntent(createPhotoFromCameraIntent());
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, intent);
    return chooser;
}
private Intent createPhotoChooserIntent(Intent... intents) {
    Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Please Choose Your Image");
    return chooser;
}
private Intent createPhotoFromCameraIntent() {
    return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

what I dont understand is why I'm not able to get anything from `intent.getData()` now?? I also insert a line break to check what I received from the intent in `onActivityResult`, and I see nothing related to the path. I was able to see `content://media/external/images/media/1249` but not anymore now....what happen to android 4.4!!??

please help.

Comment: did you find an answer for that?